# How do I properly serve images from the wwwroot to razor pages in a "Page" subfolder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, razor-pages

I have a JavaScript function that creates a fading slideshow. It uses images in the directory:

> **"wwwroot/images/backgrounds"**

If I load a page that's directly inside the **Pages** folder, the images load properly. But if I load a page that's inside a subfolder, the browser tries to get the images from inside that folder instead of from the root folder.

So instead of

> **"localhost/images/backgrounds/bg1.jpg"**

I get

> **"localhost/subfolder in 'Pages' folder/images/backgrounds/bg1.jpg"**

I'm still new to this, so I'm not sure why the wwwroot folder isn't serving the images properly, but I set my default page to one in the same subfolder and it works perfectly, so I'm at a loss at to what's wrong.

Any ideas or solutions would be greatly appreciated at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading your images from a *relative path* - that is, the path that's exactly under the *current directory*. You want it to be based on an *absolute path* - that is, off of the same directory, no matter where the page is. To do that, use a slash in the beginning of your path: `/wwwroot/images/backgrounds`

This is actually by design - imagine you had sub-directories in your web application that needed their own images. You can then load an image, like  `images/pageBackground.png` that's relative to each page the user is on - very convenient! Just remember that leading slash - which means *start this path from
the virtual root of the application instead of the current sub-directory* - and you'll get the right file!

Comment: I can't believe how simple it was! I just added a slash like you said. So it went from **"images/backgrounds/bg1.jpg"** to **"/images/backgrounds/bg1.jpg"**. One slash was all it took, it seems. Thanks a bunch.